# Rail authentication from scratch password confirmation isn't working

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, railscasts

I'm following along [Railscasts #250 Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=comments) but have an issue where the Password Confirmation can be different from the Password and the user will still be created.

..model/dealer.rb:

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :password
before_save :encrypt_password

validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
        self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
end
end
```

..controllers/dealers_controller.rb

```
class DealersController < ApplicationController
def new
@dealer = Dealer.new
end
def create
@dealer = Dealer.new(dealer_params)

if @dealer.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed Up!"
else
    render "new"
end

end

    private
    def dealer_params
      params.require(:dealer).permit(:email, :password)
    end
    end
```

..views/dealers/new.html/erb

```
<%= form_for @dealer do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>
<p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
```

Any ideas what I need to do for this to work? Two people in the comments of the Railscast had the same issue but no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add password_confirmation to your allowed params like this:

```
def dealer_params
  params.require(:dealer).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

If this doesn't help try to generate accessor for  password_confirmation too:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: Ah thanks, the params.require part I figured out on my own when it tossed an error message my way - guess its a rails 4 thing. Since this didn't toss another error I didn't know that was the issue. Will accept when it lets me

Comment: @Ryan thanks. If you are using rails 4 you can also use the has_secure_password method as shown here:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#sec-adding_a_secure_password